# Flask application authentication using windows logged in user

Tags: python-3.x, apache, flask

I am developing flask application and rest services. I have to make that application secure with os logged in user.

My application is running on windows server(Apache). If any user launches the application from any system or trying to access web services from any other application with different domain, I don't want to prompt to enter username and password, I have to authenticate with who ever logged into that system with my ldap and need to use that user details in subsequent requests.

I am using flask,Apache 2.4, Python.

It would be very appreciable for your valuable view or help.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are trying to make it so that once a user is authenticated through your LDAP server and logged into an account, you do not want to make them have to enter their credentials again on a web application.
I do not think that with your current goal it is possible to do this, but you may find [Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with [Python-LDAP](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/latest/) as a backend useful. I found [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/flask-authentication-with-ldap--cms-23101) tutorial for using the two together if you need.
Please correct me if I am wrong in my interpretation of your question.

Comment: thanks for your quick response. Yes you are correct I don't want to show login page to enter user details.  I found kerberos. But  I didn't get proper tutorial about it. Please let me know if you have any idea on this.

Comment: Do you want to know how to set up kerberos or use it with flask?

Comment: I have integrated sspi with that I am getting remote user id with that I am querying ldap to get user details. But couldn't use JIRA rest api  in subsequent to create issue. as it is not allowing any authentication other than Basic and oath. Do you have any idea to authenticate jira so reporter can track his issue or else just passing lan id in reporter is enough to create ticket on behalf of him.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not worked with JIRA at all but I'll look into using it and it's rest api